# How to configure apache return 404 for certain file extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to be able to change the extension of any file on my server to `.hide` or `._` for example.
If the file is visited `http://www.example.com/index.hide` then I would like the server to respond the same way as if the file doesn't exist.

Edit.

I would also like to make it easier to keep track of what the file extension was.

So I would actually like to prefix any extension with a `_`, e.g. from `file.xml` to `file._xml`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with

```
<FilesMatch "(\.(hide|_)|~)$">
    ## Apache 2.2
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All

    ## Apache 2.4
    # Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a 404 error status for the .hide extension, try the follow rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+\.hide [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

To handle multiple extension, you can use a OR based pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+\.(hide|foo|bar|_) [NC]
```